# Postgres database "Query has no destination for result data " error

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to convert MSSQL queries to POSTGRES queries.
I am not able to execute the below query in Postgres

```
DO $$
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM PROCESS WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM PROCESS WHERE NAME = 'TRANSACTION')) THEN
SELECT * FROM MSG
WHERE msg_timestamp >= ( SELECT start_time FROM PROCESS WHERE NAME = 'TRANSACTION' AND STATUS = 'STARTED');
ELSE
SELECT * FROM MSG;
END IF;
END $$;
```

ERROR:

> query has no destination for result data
> HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 7 at SQL statement
> FCMDBPOSTGRES=#

My corresponding MSSQL query is as below which works fine

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM PROCESS WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM PROCESS WHERE NAME = 'TRANSACTION'))
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM MSG
WHERE msg_timestamp >= ( SELECT start_time FROM PROCESS WHERE NAME = 'TRANSACTION' AND STATUS = 'STARTED')
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM MSG
END
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+%22+query+has+no+destination+for+result+data%22

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need the `do` statement for this, just plain SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM MSG
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM PROCESS WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM PROCESS WHERE NAME = 'TRANSACTION'))
    OR msg_timestamp >= (SELECT start_time FROM PROCESS WHERE NAME = 'TRANSACTION' AND STATUS = 'STARTED');
```

Or to be more verbose:

```
SELECT * FROM MSG
WHERE 
    CASE
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM PROCESS WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM PROCESS WHERE NAME = 'TRANSACTION'))
            THEN msg_timestamp >= (SELECT start_time FROM PROCESS WHERE NAME = 'TRANSACTION' AND STATUS = 'STARTED')
        ELSE TRUE
    END;
```

Or to be more simple:

```
SELECT * FROM MSG
WHERE 
    msg_timestamp >= coalesce(
        (SELECT start_time FROM PROCESS WHERE NAME = 'TRANSACTION' AND STATUS = 'STARTED'),
        '-infinity');
```

BTW If I understand correctly

```
EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM PROCESS WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM PROCESS WHERE NAME = 'TRANSACTION'))
```

could be simplified to

```
EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PROCESS WHERE NAME = 'TRANSACTION')
```

Comment: Yes to the final simplificaton. The only assumption being that `ID` is defined `NOT NULL`. Seems likely, though.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot to work. Postgres doesn't support free queries in procedures or scripts. Every result of SQL statement should be saved to variable (or returned as result of table function). More `DO` statement has not any input output mechanism. You can write table function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fx()
RETURNS SETOF MSG AS $$
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM PROCESS
              WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM PROCESS
                           WHERE NAME = 'TRANSACTION'))
  THEN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM MSG
                    WHERE msg_timestamp >= ( SELECT start_time FROM PROCESS
                            WHERE NAME = 'TRANSACTION' AND STATUS = 'STARTED');
  ELSE
    RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM MSG;
  END IF;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM fx();
```

Note: if you have experience of MSSQL procedures, then the best start for work with Postgres is an reading of documentation - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html . Lot of things are very very different. The stored procedures in Postgres are similar to Oracle, but very far to MSSQL.